# Gradle monobuild and map of jar files for all gradle composite builds

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

We have a directory structure like so

- java

  - build/build.gradle (This does NOT exist yet, but we want this)
  - servers

    - server1/build.gradle
    - server2/build.gradle
  - libraries

    - lib1/build.gradle
    - lib2/build.gradle

We have 11 servers and 14 libraries with varying uses of dependencies. EACH server is a composite build ONLY depending on libraries (we don’t allow servers to depend on each other). In this way, as our mono-repo grows, opening up server1 does NOT get slower and slower as more and more gradle code is added(ie. gradle only loads server1 and all it’s libraries and none of the other libraries OR servers are loaded keeping things FAST).

Ok, so one problem we are running into is duplication now which is why we need build/build.gradle file AND we want EVERY module in our mono repo to include that somehow for a few goals(each goal may need a different solution)

**GOAL 1: To have an ext { … } section containing a Map of Strings to gradle dependencies much like so**

```
deps = [
  'web-webserver':      "org.webpieces:http-webserver:${webpiecesVersion}",
  'web-webserver-test': "org.webpieces:http-webserver-test:${webpiecesVersion}",
  'web-devrouter':      "org.webpieces:http-router-dev:${webpiecesVersion}"
]
```

In this way, we want ALL our projects to them import dependencies like so

```
compile deps['web-webserver']
```

**GOAL 2: We want to 'include' a standard list of plugins** so we are versioning all gradle plugins the same across the repo.  While the above configures all jars to avoid jar hell in a mono-repo, we would like to do the same with just this section

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.9'
}
```

Of course, it each project may also want to add a few more plugins OR even not depend on this section(in case of an emergency and trying to just get the job done).

**GOAL 3: We want checkstyle configuration (or any plugin config) to be defined the SAME** for all projects (eventually!!!). We would like the checkstyle gradle to live in a common area but have all libraries somehow pull it in.  Again, it would be nice for it to be optional in that, I can pull the gradle section into my build.gradle OR can create a new one in case of emergencies so I don't have to fix all projects in the monorepo right away.

IDEALLY, perhaps I kind of want configuration injection where when I run server1/build.gradle, it actually runs java/build/build.grade as it’s parent somehow but with overrides (IF I declare 'extends xxx.gradle' maybe) then all libraries it uses also use java/build/build.gradle as their parent. I am not sure this is possible or feasible.  I am pretty sure 'extends xxx' doesn't exist in gradle.

Are any of these GOALS possible?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by why you don't just use a "standard" gradle top level build file and compose the others as [subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).
This solves all 3 of your goals

If you are concerned by build speed, you can target each server individually simply by running

```
./gradlew :server1:build
```

But if you are not able to do this for some reason you can use the `apply from:` syntax as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins)

Comment: Because at 100 servers, 187 libraries, the load time on that for every developers == slow as crap(ie. that solution doesn't scale well).  If you work in a monorepo where ALL projects are in one git, it is truly AWESOME when you only load what is needed for your team.  If you load more like you are saying, things get real slow, real fast. @h3adache.  monorepo done right WAY BETTER than artifactory where people tend to accidentally break other teams(that's actually impossible with the correct monorepo setup eliminate sooo many issues there).

Comment: Twitter runs a much larger monorepo.  I even looked into gradle (twitter uses pants) but gradle's support for a true monorepo at scale is not really in place just yet.  I think more and more people will make the switch (I know I did after working in a FAST monorepo....it's amazing )

Comment: The `apply from:` approach I mention in my answer above will work then.  It allows you to compose a build while keeping each 'subrepo' separate.

Comment: awesome!!! I missed that last sentence.  holy crap, this will be sick if that works out.  thanks!!!!  I am hoping I can condense all 3rd party jars into one gradle file for the mono-repo(yes, when someone upgrades a jar, it is done for all libraries and services in one go).

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on a monorepo with the exact same requirement as you, using gradle composite builds as well. The way we have solved this problem is by using [pre compiled plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins)

You need to do a new gradle project with only the code you want to share. This will create a plugin, that you can just add as a composite build and apply to the other projects.